# Python error -- local variable reference before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the message `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'adict' referenced before assignment`

But I don't understand the bug, because I defined `adict` before assigning keys and values.

```
def output(query,s_date,e_date,page,max_page):
    while page < max_page:
        s_from = s_date.replace(".","")
        e_to = e_date.replace(".","")
        url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=" + query + "&sort=0&ds=" + s_date + "&de=" + e_date + "&nso=so%3Ar%2Cp%3Afrom" + s_from + "to" + e_to + "%2Ca%3A&start=" + str(page)
        header = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
        }
        req = requests.get(url,headers=header)
        cont = req.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, 'html.parser')
        jsonfile = open(s_from+"_news_scrape_"+e_to+".json", 'w')
        news_dicts = []
        for urls in soup.select("._sp_each_url"):
            adict = dict()
            try:
                if urls["href"].startswith("https://news.naver.com"):
                    news_detail = get_news(urls["href"])
                    adict["title"] = news_detail[0]
                    adict["date"] = news_detail[1]
                    adict["company"] = news_detail[3]
                    adict["text"] = news_detail[2]
            except Exception as e:
                continue
        page += 10
        return adict
```

Any advice would be appreciated, it is taking me forever to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't verify this as I can't replicate your problem, but it looks like that sometimes your for loop does not execute at all (the `soup.select()` is returning an empty list). So I suspect that your return statement is creating the issue.

Put `adict = dict()` just before the for loop or make sure that before you return `adict` it's actually first initialised.

```
>>> def test():
...     if 1 == 2:
...         adict = dict()
...     return adict
...
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in test
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'adict' referenced before assignment
```